# How to extend click method of accordion

Tags: jquery, onclick, accordion, extend

I need to extend click method of accordion.

I have something like:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">
    <div id="toChange1">Section </div>1</a></h3>
<div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
</div>
<h3><a href="#"><div id="toChange2">Section </div>2</a></h3>
<div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
</div>
<h3><a href="#"><div id="toChange3">Section </div>3</a></h3>
<div>
    <p>
    Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis.
    Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero
    ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis
    lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>List item one</li>
        <li>List item two</li>
        <li>List item three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and i need to change background color of div inside h3. So i need to call something like:

```
$("#toChange1").css("backgroundColor","white");
```

When that header is clicked. Any suggestions? thanks!!

Comment: Something like `$("#accordion h3").click(function() { $(this).find("div").css(...); });`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could change the background color of content inside h3:

```
$("div[id^=toChange]").on('click', function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().css("background-color","red");
});
```